# How to catch an NSRangeException with do...catch?

Tags: java, swift, exception

I am translating this Java code to swift:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < groups.length ; i++) {
    try {
        groups[i] = integerPart.substring (i * 3, i * 3 + 3);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        groups[i] = integerPart.substring (i * 3);
    }
    groups[i] = new StringBuilder (groups[i]).reverse ().toString ();
    groups[i] = get1To3DigitString (groups[i]) + " " + getTheWord (i) + " ";
}
```

Note:

- `integerPart` is a string.
- `groups` is a string array.
- please ignore `get1To3DigitString` and `getTheWord`.

My thoughts and tries:

Since swift's string is really annoying (can't be indexed with `Int`), I decided to use `NSString`'s `substringFromIndex` and `substringWithRange` methods to do the `substring` Java method. So I wrote these 2 methods to help me:

```
func substring (s: String, start: Int, end: Int) throws -> String{
    let ns = NSString(string: s)
    return String(ns.substringWithRange(NSRange(start..<end)))
}

func substring (s: String, start: Int) -> String {
    let ns = NSString(string: s)
    return String(ns.substringFromIndex(start))
}
```

And I know that the two substring methods from `NSString` throws an `NSRangeException`, just like Java's `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. So here's my swift code:

```
for var i = 0 ; i < groups.count ; i++ {
    do {
        try groups[i] = substring(integerPart, start: i * 3, end: i * 3 + 3)
    } catch NSRangeException {
        groups[i] = substring(integerPart, start: i * 3)
    }
    groups[i] = String (groups[i].characters.reverse())
    groups[i] = get1To3DigitString (groups[i]) + " " + getTheWord (i) + " "
}
```

And I get an error saying the catch pattern does not match `ErrorType`! I thought it does match `ErrorType`, because if it doesn't, how am I supposed to catch the exception? So I deleted the word `NSRangeException`.

I thought if an exception is thrown in `substring`, I would catch it in the `catch` part. But when I tested it, an exception occurred on the `try` line! I think this is because I wrote the catch pattern incorrectly.

How should I catch `NSRangeException`?

Comment: *And I know that the two substring methods from NSString throws an NSRangeException* - do they?

Comment: Swifts `try/catch` is for Swift *errors* thrown with `throw`. That is completely unrelated to runtime errors or NSExceptions, which you *cannot* catch in Swift.

Comment: I tested it. They really did! I tried `substring("Hello", start: 1, end: 10)` @luk2302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like in `Java` you never ever ever catch a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` you never ever ever catch a `NSRangeException` in Swift or Objective-C.

Those exceptions are caused because you as the developer screwed up, not the application or some outside factor, or the user with his input. In `Java` you have the term *checked exceptions* and *unchecked exceptions*. The first one you can and should or even **have** to catch, the second ones occur at runtime and signal mostly bugs in the program.

You simply must not substring a String of length 5 until its tenth char - that is something you as the developer could and have to know and be aware of. If you do this, the program **should** crash.

I am not sure if you actually *can* catch a `NSRangeException` - I would be very happy if you cannot do it. For regular Errors you define custom errors types:

```
enum LevelParsingException : ErrorType {
    case MalformedJson
    case InvalidLevelContent
}
```

Then you have some function which might throw them:

```
func parseLevel() throws {
    guard someCondition {
        throw LevelParsingException.InvalidLevelContent
    }
}
```

And then you call that method and catch all the different errors that you know might arise:

```
func call() {
    do {
        try parseLevel()
    } catch LevelParsingException.InvalidLevelContent {
        print("something")
    } catch  {
        print("something else")
    }
}
```

The [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) explain that all relatively well.

Comment: You mean I should check whether the parameters for `substring` is in range first, _then_ call it?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, either check it *OR* simply make sure that you as the dev do not use the method in the wrong way.

Comment: I think you should have answered the original question instead of saying we screwed up :) What if UIKit throws this exception and I have to handle it? removeObserver method throws this (KVO) and there is no way I can check if my object is still registered to that property.

Comment: @batu if the exception is thrown you "screwed up" / introduced a bug because you missed unregistering an object you previously registered. There is **no** need to catch these exceptions if you properly code to begin with - they are only thrown if you did not properly check for edge cases and or missed some calls, etc. There is no need to check if your object is still registered - if you registered it once, you have to unregister it once.

Comment: You know, UIPageViewController is buggy has hell. For some "edge" cases, it does not call it's child view controller's viewDidDisappear method. I normally unregister there. But I need to handle those "edge" cases. I see you are confident of yourself, but I think that's a bit too much. Instead of giving a solution, you still insist I screwed up. Bugs happen and sometimes you need a safety net. That's the reality of programming.

Comment: @batu and sometimes there is no safety net. You may want to ask a separate question for your specific use case and see if someone has a proper answer in your situation, I am not too familiar with the `UIPageViewController` and its perks and bugs.